# How to filter an array that contains a specific word

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

I have an array like this

```
{
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "this is book",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "this is a test book",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "this is a desk",
  }
 ]
}
```

Now, for example, I want to return an array that contains the word `book`

I have tried the following but failed -

```
let test = this.pro.filter((s: { name: any; })=>s.name===book);
```

I also tried this but it returned the `first matching result` instead of `all matching results` -

```
let test = this.pro.filter((s: { name: any; })=>s.name===this is book);
```

Please help with a solution that can yield an array with all items that match the filter condition/s.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: change to `'book'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code will work as you expected. This checks the word 'Book' is present in the Array of object and return the particular object.

```
const pro = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "this is book",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "this is a test book",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "this is a desk",
  }]

let newArr = pro.filter(item=>{
  if(item.name.indexOf('book') > -1){
    return item;
  }
})
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: filter should return true or false. works because return "something" or null, but you can directly:`let newArr = pro.filter(item=>{return item.name.indexOf('book') > -1}})`

Answer (score 2):

Try this `let test = b.filter((s)=>s.name.includes('book'));`

Comment: that just return one result  i dont know why

Comment: if your array is  [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "this is book",
},{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "this is a test book",
},{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "this is a desk",
}]  this then its return two value